# In IIS how can i use apache htaccess details

Tags: php, apache, iis-7

Below i mentioned apache htaccess error_log specifications. How i can use same details in IIS server.

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  phperrors.log
# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files PHP_errors.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the htaccess is for the httpd server (i.e. Apache HTTP server), IIS will not use it. Instead, IIS uses Web.config file.

You would need some plugin for IIS which would take care of parsing through the htaccess file or you might need to convert the htaccess rules to equivalent Web.config rules.

https://serverfault.com/questions/30001/php-url-rewriting-with-htaccess-and-microsoft-iis-url-rewriting